# Echo After First Title In Markdown With Bash

Tags: bash, sed, markdown

I have a markdown file called `my.md`. It contains a single H1 title and a lot of other contents like:

```
# My Title

## Sub title

A lot of text and other stuff here...
```

What I want to do is that I want to insert a line after the H1 title line. To make the file look like:

```
# My Title

(my text)

## Sub title

A lot of text and other stuff here...
```

I thought of using Sed after `#`, but the problem is that it inserts it after the `#` symbol directly. While I actually want it to be in new line alone. Not in the same line.

Any ideas?

Comment: `but the problem is that it inserts it after the # symbol directly` seems like you did try to solve and got stuck.. do add that code to question, else your question might get treated as asking for free coding service..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
s='(my text)'
sed "/^# /a\\
\\
$s
" file

# My Title

(my text)

## Sub title

A lot of text and other stuff here...
```

Or using `awk`:

```
awk -v s="$s" 'p{printf "\n%s\n", s; p=0} /^# /{p=1} 1' file

# My Title

(my text)

## Sub title

A lot of text and other stuff here...
```

Comment: How can I insert a variable instead of (my text)? Like $DISPLAY, it just prints $DISPLAY literal instead of the variable using this command.

Comment: @codeforester: Appreciate your edits making the answers more readable. But be careful when you edit stuff like this, adding `-v s="$s"`. The original author might have meant to make the answer compatible with any `awk` version and with `-v` flag you have made it compatible with `GNU Awk` only. Just make sure you clarify with the original author before making such compatibility change edits.

Answer (score 2):

`sed` has append (`a`) command for appending text after a matched line. So, you can match the line with h1 (starting with single single `#`) and then put the desired text likewise:

```
sed '/^#[^#]/a \(my text)' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt                       
# My Title
## Sub title
A lot of text and other stuff here...

% sed '/^#[^#]/a \(my text)' file.txt
# My Title
(my text)
## Sub title
A lot of text and other stuff here...
```

Comment: How can I insert a variable instead of (my text)? Like $DISPLAY, it just prints $DISPLAY literal instead of the variable using this command.

Comment: @Madno Thats because of the single quotes, do: sed '/^#[^#]/a \'"$DISPLAY" file.txt

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
cat <<! | sed '/^#\s/r /dev/stdin' file

$DISPLAY

!
```

This appends a here-document to the address matched in file by sed.

Answer (score 0):

try following too once and let me know if this helps.

```
awk -v my_text="your_text_here..." '{printf("%s\n",/^##/?my_text ORS ORS $0:$0)}'  Input_file
```

**Explanation:** Creating a variable named my_text whose value will be your text which you want to insert in between. Now using printf here and in that checking conditions if any line is starting from ## then print variable then 2 new lines(ORS) output record separator whose default value will be new line then current line, if any line doesn't start with ## then print it simply.